# Mod Rewrite: Leading slash followed by parameter after domain name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule that changes a URLwith parameters into just a forward slash followed by a parameter.

The RewriteRule:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ send.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]`

The above rule should then work for the URL:
`example.com/google.com`

But although the URL `example.com/google.com` remains in the browser bar and I do not get a 404 or 500 server error, instead of adding google.com as a parameter, `send.php` is added as the URL parameter instead.

The URL should go to:
`send.php?url=google.com&name=&submit=submit`
But it currently goes to:
`send.php?url=send.php&name=&submit=submit`

Interestingly if I change the `RewriteRule` slightly, everything works fine.
Working `RewriteRule`
`RewriteRule ^send/(.*)$ /send.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]`

Here's a copy of the log for both working and not working versions of the `RewriteRule`.
Log for (working)`RewriteRule ^send/(.*)$ /send.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]`

[Tue Oct 11 11:03:09.500902 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6376:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:14876] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#611988][rid#2f16c40/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send -> C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:03:09.500902 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6376:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:14876] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#611988][rid#2f16c40/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send/google.com -> send/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:03:09.500902 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6376:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:14876] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#611988][rid#2f16c40/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] applying pattern '^send/(.*)$' to uri 'send/google.com'

[Tue Oct 11 11:03:09.500902 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 6376:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:14876] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#611988][rid#2f16c40/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] rewrite 'send/google.com' -> '/send.php?url=google.com&name=&submit=submit'

[Tue Oct 11 11:03:09.500902 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6376:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:14876] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#611988][rid#2f16c40/initial] split uri=/send.php?url=google.com&name=&submit=submit -> uri=/send.php, args=url=google.com&name=&submit=submit

Log for (not working)`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ send.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]`

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3314c38/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/google.com -> google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3314c38/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'google.com'

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3314c38/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] rewrite 'google.com' -> 'send.php?url=google.com&name=&submit=submit'

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3314c38/initial] split uri=send.php?url=google.com&name=&submit=submit -> uri=send.php, args=url=google.com&name=&submit=submit

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3314c38/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] add per-dir prefix: send.php -> C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send.php

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3314c38/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] strip document_root prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send.php -> /send.php

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3314c38/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] internal redirect with /send.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#331af78/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send.php -> send.php

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#331af78/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'send.php'

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#331af78/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] rewrite 'send.php' -> 'send.php?url=send.php&name=&submit=submit'

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#331af78/initial/redir#1] split uri=send.php?url=send.php&name=&submit=submit -> uri=send.php, args=url=send.php&name=&submit=submit

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#331af78/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] add per-dir prefix: send.php -> C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send.php

[Tue Oct 11 11:21:58.485476 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#331af78/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send.php [IGNORING REWRITE]

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.862783 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3316c40/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/css -> C:/xampp/htdocs/test/css/style.css, referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.862783 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3316c40/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/css/style.css -> css/style.css, referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.862783 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3316c40/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'css/style.css', referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.862783 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3316c40/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] rewrite 'css/style.css' -> 'send.php?url=css/style.css&name=&submit=submit', referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.862783 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3316c40/initial] split uri=send.php?url=css/style.css&name=&submit=submit -> uri=send.php, args=url=css/style.css&name=&submit=submit, referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.862783 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3316c40/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] add per-dir prefix: send.php -> C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send.php, referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.862783 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3316c40/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] strip document_root prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send.php -> /send.php, referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.862783 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3316c40/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] internal redirect with /send.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT], referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.863783 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3319138/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send.php -> send.php, referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.863783 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3319138/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'send.php', referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.863783 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3319138/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] rewrite 'send.php' -> 'send.php?url=send.php&name=&submit=submit', referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.863783 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3319138/initial/redir#1] split uri=send.php?url=send.php&name=&submit=submit -> uri=send.php, args=url=send.php&name=&submit=submit, referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.863783 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3319138/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] add per-dir prefix: send.php -> C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send.php, referer: http://example.com/google.com

[Tue Oct 11 11:22:03.863783 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5176:tid 1632] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:15724] 127.0.0.1 - - [example.com/sid#3e1988][rid#3319138/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/test/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: C:/xampp/htdocs/test/send.php [IGNORING REWRITE], referer: http://example.com/google.com

Looking at the log it gets it correct to begin with: `url=google.com`, but then further along changes to `url=send.php`

So in summary, how can I turn this URL: `example.com/send.php?url=google.com&name=&submit=submit`
into this URL: `example.com/google.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ send.php?url=$1&name=&submit=submit [NC,L]
```

This way you avoid to rewrite existing files and directories.

With `-f` you test for files, and with `-d` for directories.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Thank you so much. This works as desired!! I can't believe after all the different things I've tried, that I obviously didn't try this. I see those conditions all over the place, but don't quite understand how they work even after reading the docs. In the context of the above code would you mind breaking down what's happening here??

Comment: Yes. In the answer.